# Listing all resources in Azure in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-sdk-js

I am trying to use the Azure SDK for Javascript to list all the resources within an Azure subscription. My approach has been to authenticate using the `@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth` package and then call ResourceManagementClient from the `@azure/arm-resources` package but I am having several issues.

#### 1. App registration

I have opted to use `msRestNodeAuth.loginWithServicePrincipalSecretWithAuthResponse()`. I went into AzureAD and created a new app registration and then within that a secret. This gives me a clientId, a secret and a tenantId that I can supply to the function.

However, the issue I feel I will face (once I actually get my code working) is permissioning. I have no idea what permissions need to be applied to this app registration to allow it to query resources like this.

I cannot see this described in any of the docs that I've looked at.

#### 2. ESM / CJS issues

I am running v12.16.1 of NodeJS. In order to use the ESM import syntax I am supplying the `--experimental-modules` flag along with `es-module-specifier-resolution=node` so that file extensions do not need to be supplied when importing (the `package.json` file also has `type: "module"` set). This has worked fine across many packages, but on the two packages above the imports seem have a wrapper meaning that I need to call `.default` in order to access the actual function:

[image]

For example:

```
import * as msRestNodeAuth from "@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth";
const res = await msRestNodeAuth.loginWithServicePrincipalSecretWithAuthResponse(_clientId, _secretValue, _tennantId);
```

...must become:

```
import * as msRestNodeAuth from "@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth";
const res = await msRestNodeAuth.default.loginWithServicePrincipalSecretWithAuthResponse(_clientId, _secretValue, _tennantId);
```

The code works when doing this, but my guess is that something is off with how the package has been built / how my NodeJS setup is configured. I also cannot import `ResourceManagementClient` from `@azure/arm-resources`, instead having to do this:

```
// This errors:
// import { ResourceManagementClient } from "@azure/arm-resources";
// ...but I can access it like:
import * as armResources from "@azure/arm-resources";

const client = new armResources.default.ResourceManagementClient();
```

#### 3. Putting it all together

When I try to put it all together and get a list of resource groups, I get an error:

```
const res = await msRestNodeAuth.default.loginWithServicePrincipalSecretWithAuthResponse(_clientId, _secretValue, _tennantId);

const client = new armResources.default.ResourceManagementClient(res.credentials, _subscriptionId);

const resourceGroups = await client.resourceGroups.list();
```

> The client 'XYZ123' with object id 'abc678' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/read' over scope '/subscriptions/123213123' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

My hope is that this is just an auth error that will resolve when issue #1 is fixed - i.e. the app registration gets the permissions it needs.

Apologies for the broad scope of this question; I am used to doing this in AWS so I am trying to get to grips with both Azure and this SDK at the same time. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You would need to grant Azure RBAC role to your Service Principal. Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to list all Azure resource in one subscription, you need to assign read role at subscription level. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#all) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview)
[image]

Regarding how to assign the role to sp, we can use [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-powershell) to implement it

```
$id=(Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName <principalName>).id
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $id `
-RoleDefinitionName Reader `
-Scope /subscriptions/<subscriptionId>
```

Comment: Fantastic, this worked! Is there anywhere in the Azure Portal that I can see these permissions? The app registration in the portal doesn't list it anywhere that I can see. Where do I need to look? Using Powershell is OK but I'd like to be able to view it in the webpage.

Comment: @MSOACC please refer to http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/view-applications-portal